# Laravel routing issue when upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: laravel

I upgraded my server to Ubuntu 17.10 and created a new project via composer. 
I get the Laravel default page, but when creating a new route (in `web.php`) and creating a new route for `/about`, I get a page not found, however when I code `/index.php/about` I get the correct page.

It must be something simple, but my eyes are crossing.

Comment: You haven't configured your webserver (typically nginx/Apache) properly. The docs include example configs for both, IIRC.

Comment: Does your vhost has the public folder as root dir ?

Comment: I think ceekayoz is right -- for example, Laravel docs should have an .htaccess file you can place in your project root to enable routing on your linux server.

Comment: first, check whether [rewrite_mod](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is installed or not. second, check `.htaccess` in laravel's `/public` directory - make sure its still the original, unless you had some changes (that may broke it anyway). third, pray that both of the items to check above gave some clue. it is very unlikely that your routes got cached. let us know if something unclear.